# Clicking on a link, takes me to the bottom of the page instead of the place from where I called it

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

As soon as I click on 'Hide' link below, my page goes to the bottom. How can I make it go to the place from where it opened?

**My code:**

```
<li><a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('basic2')">How do I maximize battery life?</a></li>

<div id="basic2" style="display:none; background-color:#fff; padding:5px; margin-left: 11px;">
    <p>Wadfasfsafasfas</p>
    <a href="#" onclick="ReverseDisplay('basic2');">Hide</a></li>
    <div id="basic2" style="display:none; background-color:#fff; padding:5px; margin-left: 11px;">
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <hr />
</div>
```

**Function:**

```
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
    if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none")
    {
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: One possible issue is that you have two div elements with the same ID.

Comment: I already removed one...but still the problem persists..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an onClick in a link (like `onclick="ReverseDisplay('basic2');"` you want to make sure it returns `false`.

Something like this should work : `onclick="ReverseDisplay('basic2');return false;"`

Comment: Hi guys, Following is the code i Use, it is very unusual but as soon as i click on Hide, it reaches to bottom only, I m really pissed.                                                  function iClose()
{
$('#basic2').hide(); 
}

<li><a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('basic2')">How do I maximize battery life?</a></li>

<div id="basic2" style="display:none; background-color:#fff; padding:5px; margin-left: 11px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="iClose();">Hide</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr />
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You've got duplicate element ids "basic2"

**Edit**
I think what you're looking for is something like this. Where "Hide" toggles the parent element:

```
<li><a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('basic1')">How do I maximize battery life?</a></li>
<div id="basic1" style="display:none; background-color:#fff; padding:5px; margin-left: 11px;">
    <p>Wadfasfsafasfas</p>
    <a href="#" onclick="ReverseDisplay('basic1');">Hide</a></li>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <hr />
</div>
<script>
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have removed it and then tried then also the problem persists..I out href= javascript:void(0) and returned false from the calling method,but i dont know why it goes to bottom every time, I had simply tried to hide it using jquery(div).hide but it also dint work. Do u think, any other possibility..thanks for ur time